# What is "spectral development" of a linear operator?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators, spectral-sequences

I want to find the "spectral development" (or spectral series, spectral decomposition, not sure how to translate to english) of the linear operator.

What is that? I can't even google it. I think it is not singular value decomposition.

The operaror is
$T(x_1, x_2,...) = (0, x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, \frac{x_3}{3},...)$
from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2$.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)

Comment: Yeah, it may turn out that it's just those three sets when I think again. Thanks

Comment: "spectral development" is the same thing as (in finite dimension) eigenvalue decomposition under the form $\sum \lambda_k U_k^TV_k$

Answer (score 0):

This is a compact operator with no eigenvalues: the spectrum consists of $0$ alone.  So the decomposition is trivial: the generalized eigenspace for $0$ is the whole space.